# Voronoi Diagram query

Tags: r, voronoi

I have created a voronoi plot in R 
gave the point labels

using the code:

```
install.packages("deldir") 
library(deldir)  
x <- runif(20); y <- runif(20); window <- c(0,1,0,1) 
tess <- deldir(x, y, rw = window) 
plot.deldir(tess, wpoints="real", wlines="tess") 
label=c('a','b','c'.....'t')
library(plotrix)
thigmophobe.labels(x, y, labels=label)
```

can someone suggest a query so that,
if i give a location of a new point which is in the cell containing point 'a'
the output should be 'a'.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the voronoi tesselation is the boundary line between nearest points, your problem simply reduces to finding the nearest neighbour.

You can do this by computing a distance matrix using `dist()` and then extracting the point with minimum distance.

Try this:

```
library(deldir)  

n <- 20
dat <- data.frame(
  x = runif(n),
  y =runif(n)
)

tess <- deldir(dat, rw = c(0,1,0,1)) 
plot.deldir(tess, wpoints="none", wlines="tess", col="blue") 
label=letters[1:n]
text(dat, labels=label)


for (i in 1:500){
  newdat <- data.frame(x=runif(1), y=runif(1))
  np <- which.min(unname(as.matrix(dist(rbind(newdat, dat), diag=FALSE))[-1, 1]))

  text(newdat, col="red", labels=label[np], cex=0.5)
}
```

[image]

Comment: we are comparing distance with each and every point. so the purpose of sectors is not being served here. so any other code that makes the use of the sectors?

Comment: @ChakradharGavireddy I don't understand your question.  I think I answered the question as posed.  If you have a different query, then I suggest you ask a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a point-location test:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location.